# My horse died - do I have to buy another?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was trying to find the 7000 Steps, when I fell about 4 feet, and my horse died. I already tried to fast travel and nothing happened, so do I have to buy another horse?

Answer (score 6):

Horses do not respawn after death in Skyrim, you will have to buy another. If you only want to climb to High Hrothgar I suggest stealing one (without being seen) from the Whiterun stables.

Answer (score 0):

No, your horse does not respawn, you will have to buy another horse. But if this happens again I recommend you to load your last save/ auto save when you did have your horse.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! We expect new answers to add additional ideas in a meaningful way. Unfortunately this is not really a meaningful addition to the existing ideas.

Comment: It has some additional contribution compared to the previous answer in the recommendation of to load your last save/auto save. It just isn't much of a contribution and is generally assumed.

Answer (score 0):

My first horse died from some bandits, but to my surprise I found it again at Whiterun Stables after a couple days, where I originally bought it. Its behaviour was changed, though, now it always walks off towards Whiterun Stables as soon as I dismount it.